# Oracle 12c db_link usage count

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration, dblink

DB: Oracle12cR1

In Oracle12cR1, is there a way or views to list how many times userA have invoked db_links in a day from source database?

Comment: There is an Oracle Support Note on the topic, Doc ID 2071002.1. You can read it if you have a My Oracle Support license. [Find it here](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2071002_1.html).

Comment: @APC, thank you for comments. Oracle metalink was the first place I searched, did looked into Doc ID 2071002.1 but it ask to query on remote destination db and not on source db.    If source db is going to multiple databases then I will have to query on all of them.